# strange PDOException error 1153

Tags: javascript, database, css-js-aggregation

This morning my Drupal 7 site suddenly not working. I get the
"PDOException: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153" error. The error goes away when I disabled "Aggregate JavaScript files." in config/development/performance page. I clear the cache several time, but when I re-enable "Aggregate JavaScript files" the error comes back.

This error happens only on certain pagee.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem? It doesn't make any sense to me. Thansk.

Answer (score 4):

i think you need to increase your [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) in your my.cnf/my.ini in mysql,
maybe the problem is with packet size.

Comment: But why would enabling javascript aggregation affect this?

Comment: @Patrick Probably because during aggregation a string is being written to the cache table that's bigger than the `max_allowed_packet` for whatever reason. This used to happen to me all the time and it was always related to the cache tables

Answer (score 3):

[Error 1153](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html) is to do with the MySQL configuration option, [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). If you increase this then you shouldn't have this problem anymore.